# How do I pass data from login to another page

Tags: react-native, redux

I am new to react-native and redux. I have successfully created a login function which calls a post-request api. The credentials insert by a user are matric no and password. I have another post-method api need to be called to display a list of data in another page after the user successfully logged on. However I dunno how to pass the matric no  to another page since there is no event that ought to trigger the user to enter their matric no i order to call the post-method api. Can somebody help me how to solve this?

Comment: After Login Request is a success, in its callback you can call another action that get you the data and stores it into the redux store. And after successful redirection to the intended component you can read data from store in this component

Comment: how do I access the data from the store? and can i just directly put the api call in the componentWillMount?

Answer (score 0):

Use Redux Store or AsyncStorage to store important login information like `token` or your `matrix no`.

Retrieve on next page in `componentWillMount()` and send to Ajax to validate and get data.

ref : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. so I did implement redux, but i dunno how to retrieve the api call in componentwillmount(). Fyi, I put the api call in a separate file. So, how do I pass together the token and retrieve the api in componentWillMount()?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use [react redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). Using this u can acess anything from anywhere fast and simple.

Its a little hard to setup but once u have setup its easy to manage and u get info anywhere in the app refer this link: [Getting started with Redux](https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053).

It covers different aspects of using redux. Starting off with a simple example of counter. It also deals with how to manage an api call where the result can be accessed anywhere from the app.

Good luck!